# Allow in-house application administrative rights within corporate AD domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, certificate

We have a couple of in-house developed application in the company and those application need to be able to use "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\RegAsm.exe" in order to register components periodically which our programmer is updating constantly. And this action of course require local administrative rights while users have none.

Is there any way to allow a certain in-house developed application to work with local administrator rights on user PCs? Through some AD policies maybe?

We thought about signing the application and adding certificate in to the trusted certificate store but it will only allow to bypass UAC but I can't see any way to use it to grant more rights to the signed application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot achieve what you want via Group Policies.

You may find some useful hints here, but these are primarily programmer stuff:

[Calling regasm without administrative rights for COM interop in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23063552/calling-regasm-without-administrative-rights-for-com-interop-in-excel-vba/23073183#23073183)

[COM Interop without regasm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354581/com-interop-without-regasm/23077042#23077042)

Or you can try some application virtualization technologies.